# How to generate negative random value in python

Tags: python, random

I am starting to learn python, I tried to generate random values by passing in a negative and positive number. Let say  `-1`, `1`.

How should I do this in python?

Answer (score 35):

Use [`random.uniform(a, b)`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform)

```
>>> import random
>>> random.uniform(-1, 1)
0.4779007751444888
>>> random.uniform(-1, 1)
-0.10028581710574902
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import random

def r(minimum, maximum):
    return minimum + (maximum - minimum) * random.random()

print r(-1, 1)
```

EDIT: @San4ez's `random.uniform(-1, 1)` is the correct way. No need to reinvent the wheel…

Anyway, `random.uniform()` is coded as:

```
def uniform(self, a, b):
    "Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding."
    return a + (b-a) * self.random()
```

Comment: `def rand(): return 4 # Generated by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random.`

Comment: Thanks a lot.But cann't i do in this way.Where  i want to pass the value as a argument while running the script.                                                             .#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys , random 
r = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]
print random.range(y,r)

Comment: @user1393251 - you can do it this way (my `r` method is called the same way the correct `random.uniform` is), just I am reinventing the wheel here… Take San4ez's answer.

Answer (score 5):

> ## **If you want a random *whole* number from a given interval**

Example:

```
from random import randint
randint(-1,1)               --> Randomly returns one of the following: -1, 0, 1
```

*interval [-1, 1]*

Answer (score 4):

if you want [integer in a specified range](http://docs.python.org/library/random#random.randrange):

```
print random.randrange(-1, 2)
```

it uses the same convention as `range`, so the upper limit is not included.

`random.uniform` does something similar if you need float values, but it's [not always clear](http://docs.python.org/library/random#random.uniform) if the upper limit is included or not

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have a function that will return a random number in the range [0, 1], which you can then manipulate to suite the range you need. In python, the function is `random.random`. So for your range of [-1, 1], you can do this:

```
import random
random_number = random.random() * 2 - 1
```

By doubling the number we get a range of [0, 2], and by subtracting one from it, we get [-1, 1].

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this

```
import random
random.choice([-1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want n random values in a positive, negative or mixed range you can use random.sample(range(min,max), population).

The constraint is that distance(max-min) must be lower or equal than population value. In the example above you can generate at most 6 values

```
>> import random
>> random.sample(range(-3,3), 5) 
[-2, -3, 2, -1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to work on a list comprehension:

```
print([x for x in [random.randint(1, 11) * -1]])
```

or

```
#int range is n1 to n2
def make_negative(n1, n2):
    print([x for x in [random.randint(n1, n2) * -1]])

make_negative(1,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this today.

```
 random.randint(a, b)
```

where B > A or B is greater than A

So if we put -999 instead of A and 1 instead of B

It will give us a negative random integer or 0 and 1.

Also, this is a rule in Mathematics, bigger negative numbers are smaller in value than smaller negative numbers, like -999 < -1

This rule can be applied here!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate 2 random integers between 2 negative values than `print(f"{-random.randint(1, 5)}")` can also do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```py
random.randint(-999,-1)
```